# Metrics on a weekly level, and then averaged across all weeks for the given period

Tags: sql, mysql, presto

My manager want all these metrics on a weekly level and then averaged across all the weeks.

```
    WITH RegisteredUsers AS (
    SELECT
        e.organization_uuid,
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_uuid) AS TotalRegisteredUsers
    FROM
        u4b.dim_employee AS e
    GROUP BY
        e.organization_uuid
),
ActiveUsers AS (
    SELECT
        e.organization_uuid,
        COUNT(DISTINCT e.user_uuid) AS TotalActiveUsers
    FROM
        u4b.dim_employee AS e
    INNER JOIN uberpool.hcv_fact_trip AS t ON e.user_uuid = t.client_uuid
    WHERE
        fact_trip_status IN ('completed', 'fare_split')
        AND t.datestr BETWEEN '{{start_date}}' AND '{{end_date}}'
    GROUP BY
        e.organization_uuid
),
RiderTrips AS (
    SELECT
        e.organization_uuid,
        COUNT(*) AS RiderTripCount
    FROM
        u4b.dim_employee AS e
        INNER JOIN uberpool.hcv_fact_trip AS t ON e.user_uuid = t.client_uuid
    WHERE
        fact_trip_status IN ('completed', 'fare_split')
        AND t.datestr BETWEEN '{{start_date}}' AND '{{end_date}}'
    GROUP BY
        e.organization_uuid
)
SELECT
    ru.organization_uuid,
    COALESCE(TotalRegisteredUsers, 0) AS "Registered Users",
    COALESCE(TotalActiveUsers, 0) AS "Active Users",
    CASE
        WHEN COALESCE(TotalRegisteredUsers, 0) = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (COALESCE(TotalActiveUsers, 0) * 100) / COALESCE(TotalRegisteredUsers, 0)
    END AS "Percentage of Active Users",
    COALESCE(RiderTripCount / TotalActiveUsers, 0) AS "Trips per Rider (TpR)"
FROM
    RegisteredUsers ru
LEFT JOIN ActiveUsers au ON ru.organization_uuid = au.organization_uuid
LEFT JOIN RiderTrips rt ON ru.organization_uuid = rt.organization_uuid
ORDER BY "Active Users" DESC;
```

Output :

```
organization_uuid   Registered Users    Active Users    Percentage of Active Users  Trips per Rider (TpR)
23232   41650   2331    5   44
32325   11662   2133    18  30
32323   7920    1639    20  23
56565   2012    77338  15
73847   9495    7207   16
```

Now my manager want  that these metrics need to be on a weekly level, and then averaged across all weeks for the given period, Please help me with that I'm newbie to the sql. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with enough sample data to illustrate the use cases and then show the result you want to achieve

Comment: I've updated it. please check

Comment: you don't seem to have added any sample data

Comment: My bad it was not saved, now i've made changes as you asked. please have a look. thanks

Comment: Still no sample data, only result data. Also can you format data as tables so that the columns line up and it's readable (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)